# Atomic update to file with many concurrent readers?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, filesystems, transactional

I need to enable many concurrent threads (in one process) to read from a file (randomly) in a thread safe manner while another thread is writing (randomly) to it. FileStream.Flush does not seem to be atomic if I'm not mistaken so how is a situation like this solved? Do I need to wrap my streams and implement some kind of ReadersWriter-lock around the real stream? Would it be possible to write something lock-free?

Are there any solutions for this in .NET already that I have missed? Memory mapped files seem to have the same limitation with not having a atomic Flush. Writes and reads are thread-safe but multiple writes are not flushed atomically I think? I can't use NTFS so TxF is not an option.

**Update**: I tried writing a custom Stream-wrapper that kept all writes in a list of uncommitted buffers and then atomically swapped out that buffer on all read-streams so that they all instantly got the new version even before it had been flushed to the underlying stream. But the code got messy and I still needed locking here and there so I abandoned that idea. Think I will try a more basic approach with a readers-writer-lock. I just noticed FileStream.Lock but it seem to throw contention-exceptions instead of waiting but I guess it is more appropriate for cross-process locking. I'm just interested in single-process locking so I think I can do a more fancy solutions instead.

**Update 2**: I went with a locking approach on a single stream, locking both reader and writer, but in a manner that don't throw contention-exceptions but rather using a spin-wait until a lock is freed. Tried some performance testing on that versus having multiple read streams (and allowing concurrent readers) but saw only a very slight performance boost with the multi-stream version. The extra code complexity made it not worth it.

Comment: Have only one thread perform the reading and writing, all other threads submit requests to that thread via a service or message queue.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/blob/master/src/Lucene.Net/Store/NativeFSLockFactory.cs).

Comment: I need high throughput on reading so I can't single thread reading. Ideally I don't want locking even when writing but that seem pretty complicated to get. I think I'll resort to having a basic readers-writer-lock so locking only occurs for all threads while a single thread is writing. That could be good enough.

Comment: If you require a high throughput, a single thread accessing the file is probably still the best solution because disk operations will most likely dominate the runtime anyway. In a dedicated thread, you could also hold a copy of the data in memory to serve reading threads while writing new data to the file.